# session.auto_start =0 / problem with login to backend

Tags: shopware, shopware5

Did someone have similar problem that session.auto_start is set to 0 but shopware see it a a wrong configuration?   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhN7m.png)

I can login to the backend only using incognito mode (and I think that it can be due wrong configuration)  . Any Ideas?

thank you

Comment: Did you try to clean all your cookies?

Comment: @Alex yes, without success

Answer (score 0):

The displaying of the warning is a known bug in Shopware 5.
See [issue ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/SW-26366)

The login problem must have another cause. Please provide more information, about the Shopware version, PHP version, used plugins and other system relevant information.

Comment: Thank you!
What can be a problem? maybe some plugin try to set some  cookie/ or session and  it allow login me to the backend when I am in incognito mode?
Plugin list is very big (40 plugins + 20 individual ).
SW version: 5.7.11
 PHP Version 8.0.21

Comment: and other setting in server configuration are "green" 
thank you!

Comment: I have made a few more test and this is what I have discover:
0. I have deactivate all additonal plugins. 

1. Try to login to admin panel :  www.myshop.de/admin

2. shopware try to login and show again login panel ( see video :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzshbrgr5fcixba/backend%20login.webm )

3. when I add into url browser some extra param like www.myshop.de/admin?test=1  it login in to the backend!!  and everything is working)

Comment: okay, that is totally strange. right now, I have not clue, was could cause such behaviour :/